# The hair is emitting from the origin point of my mesh (It's a half cirlce)

Tags: particles, hair

Ok, I don't understand this, I have a half-circle which is supposed to be an eyelid. Hair is emitting from the rest of the head and I need to do the ears and the eyelids. But instead of emitting from the mesh (**half-circle**) the hair just emits from the origin point of the circle. Also if I choose *emitter particles* instead of *hair particles* it emits from the mesh, so I'm having this problem just with the hair.

[image: screenshot of emitted hair]

[image: hair emmitted from eyeball]

-*IThinkArtIsFun*

Comment: Have you applied Scale and Location to the half-circle? Are there other modifiers before (top-down) the Particle System modifier? Have you specified a vertex group for the Density?

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes caused by not having `Use Modifier Stack` checked under `Particle Settings > Emission > Source`

There are a few other issues that can crop up when working with particles and modifiers, but this is the most common one I see.

[image: Use Modifier Stack]